# How to detect exactly if authentication fail because username or password incorrect in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Using Spring Security, I can check if user input correct username/password or not. If fail, I need to determine exactly the cause, it's because the username or the password or both, to return the message accordingly.

My current code always return for me error 401 with message `Bad Credentials` whenever it's fail in the authentication process. I want to custom it to return like `Wrong username` when the username is incorrect, or `Wrong password` for the incorrect password.

I have defined custom filter and authentication entry point for the application.

```
public class JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  ....

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws AuthenticationException {

      String username = request.getParameter("username");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");

      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,
        password, Collections.emptyList());
      return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
  }

  @Override
  protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
      String username = request.getParameter("username");
      try {
          // Do some process stuff....
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         log.error(ex);
      }
      super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
  }
}
```

The config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private JwtAuthenticationExceptionEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.headers().cacheControl();
     http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
     http.csrf().disable();
     http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
        .addFilter(new JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, userService, accessHistoryService))
        .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig)).authorizeRequests();

     http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/1/**").hasRole(RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/test/**").hasAnyRole(RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/report/**").hasAnyRole(RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN, RoleConstant.ROLE_REPORT)
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
     // If a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
     http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login");

     //test in browser
     http.httpBasic();
  }
}
```

Comment: To common practice is NOT to return if the error is due to a username or password error. 
The idea behind that is that you don't want to give a potential attacker too much information (e.g. he will be able to know that he got the username right and now he needs to only get the password right. Or the other way around...)

Answer (score 0):

Just throw different `AuthenticationException` from the `authenticationManager` for different error cases during the authentication process. The thrown `AuthenticationException` will be propagated to `unsuccessfulAuthentication()` when it is invoked such that you can check if the `AuthenticationException` is a certain type of instance to determine the exactly failure reason.

If you are using the default `AuthenticationProvider` that deals with the `UserDetails` (i.e. `DaoAuthenticationProvider`), it will by default throw `BadCredentialsException` no matter the error is due to the user is not found or the password is wrong for best practise reason such that it does not reveal too much information to the attackers. But if you indeed want to do it , you can set [`hideUserNotFoundExceptions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.html#setHideUserNotFoundExceptions-boolean-) in `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to `false` such that it will throw `UsernameNotFoundException` when the user is not found and `BadCredentialsException` if the password is invalid.

Comment: I'm using the default `AuthenticationProvider` which is `DaoAuthenticationProvider` as you said. Can you show me how to set the property to false?